# Angular 4 test fails when SetTimeout is used

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I have written a very simple test which is expect component to be truthy. it was working but as soon I put a SetTimeOut in oninit it started failing with below.

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let appComponent: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    var errorMessages = new Array<ErrorMessage>();
    errorMessages.push(new ErrorMessage(500));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        MessagesModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: TestHelper.createAuthServiceSpy() },
        { provide: ErrorHandlingService, useValue: TestHelper.createErrorHandlingServiceSpy(errorMessages) }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    appComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    expect(appComponent).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should show error in case of failure', async(() => {
    expect(appComponent.errorMessage.length).toBe(1);
  }));

  it('should get username for loggedin user', async(() => {
    expect(appComponent.username).toBe("username");
  }));
});
```

All 3 of them fails and when i commented SetTimeOut it started passing.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    username: string = "";
    errorMessage: Message[] = [];
    showError: boolean = false;
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
    constructor(public authService: AuthService, private renderer: Renderer, private errorhandlingService: ErrorHandlingService, private router: Router, private titleService: Title) {
        localStorage.removeItem(AppConstants.authenticationLocalStorageKey);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                var title = this.getTitle(this.router.routerState, this.router.routerState.root).join('-');
                this.titleService.setTitle(title);
            }
        });

        this.errorhandlingService.getErrors().subscribe(errorMessages => {
            let errorMessage: ErrorMessage = errorMessages.pop();
            this.errorMessage = errorMessage ? [{ severity: 'error', summary: `Error Code: ${errorMessage.statusCode}`, detail: `(${errorMessage.text})` }] : [];
            this.renderer.setElementProperty(document.body, "scrollTop", 0);
            this.showError = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.showError = false;
            }, AppConstants.errorMessageFadeTime);
        });
        this.authService.getUsername().subscribe(data => this.username = data
            , error => this.errorhandlingService.handleError(error, 'could not get username'));
    }

    onDeactivate() {
        //scroll to top of page after routing
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(document.body, "scrollTop", 0);
    }

    private getTitle(state, parent) {
        var data = [];
        if (parent && parent.snapshot.data && parent.snapshot.data.title) {
            data.push(parent.snapshot.data.title);
        }

        if (state && parent) {
            data.push(... this.getTitle(state, state.firstChild(parent)));
        }
        return data;
    }


}
```

below is html

```
<div>
        <div class="center-text">
            <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="showError"><p-messages [value]="errorMessage"></p-messages></div>
            <router-outlet (deactivate)="onDeactivate()"></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried fakesync and done but still getting same error, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a fake class as below,

```
let errorOccured = false;

class FakeAuthService {
    getErrors(){
     return Observable.of(errorOccured);
    }
}

  providers: [
    { provide: AuthService, useClass: FakeAuthService},

  ]
```

Inject it to the `TestBed` `beforeEach` by

```
authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
```

declare a variable as in `beforeEach async`

```
let authService : AuthService
```

Update 1 :

Have the `setTimeOut` logic inside the completion event of the subscription as

```
this.errorhandlingService.getErrors().subscribe(errorMessages => {
    let errorMessage: ErrorMessage = errorMessages.pop();
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage ? [{ severity: 'error', summary: `Error Code: ${errorMessage.statusCode}`, detail: `(${errorMessage.text})` }] : [];
    this.renderer.setElementProperty(document.body, "scrollTop", 0);
    this.showError = true;

},error=>{},

()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.showError = false;
    }, AppConstants.errorMessageFadeTime);
});
```

Comment: your suggestion is valid but I am creating the spy. problem is one of the test needs to go in error subscribe function. like 2nd test. I have updated the code so that you can have full view. maybe re-write answer a little more or explanation?

Comment: auth service has nothing to do with failing code. subscriber of error message service has SetTimeOut()

Comment: I want to understand why `setTimeOut`  is used.

Comment: because i want to hide the error message after 5 seconds. if i dont it stays there until user clicks X.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion, I have just tried it and its not working which makes sense because finally will run anyway.I think we need to somehow tell Angular to wait for SetTimeout to finish (not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second section of code is in your actual service and not the tests:

the `async` callback provided by Angular looks and waits for asynchronous code like `Observables`, `Promises` and `setTimeouts`. It tries to resolve the component-under-test's method calls before checking the answer.

Jasmine itself has a configuration option called `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`. In asynchronous tests (just using jasmine, not Angular's test tools), you can pass a method called `done()` into an `it` block and Jasmine will wait a certain interval for that method to be called. This is to test asynchronous tests. The default timeout is 5 seconds, so if you're calling a timeout of 5000, that might not be enough time for Jasmine to check because of setTimeout execution shenanigans.

Angular's `async` wraps the Jasmine `done()` in a nice little call that will execute the tests after async functions have completed.

Either way, you would only want to use `async` in tests that *are asynchronous*. If a test doesn't have an async result, don't make the test wait for one.

In your case, you can set a `beforeEach` block for the async tests and either wrap your `assert`s in a timeout greater than 5000, or you can change the jasmine config for just those tests:

```
... previous tests

describe('timeout tests', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 5250;
  });

  it('should display error for five seconds', async(() => {
     ...tests
  }));

});
... more tests
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried your suggestion and still failing...i think its more tricky than we think it is.